# Why don't these water droplets fall? Is it because of the surface tension of the water?

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics, surface-tension, adhesion

Why don't these water droplets fall? Is it because of the surface tension of water?

Under the action of gravity, water tends to fall, so the pressure at the top of the water droplet is lower than atmospheric pressure, so atmospheric pressure is the reason why the water does not fall. Of course, the surface tension of water is also the reason why the water does not fall.

Am I right?

[image]

Comment: "so the pressure at the top of water is lower than atmospheric pressure" is wrong, both adhesion and surface tension hold the drop as it is small enough

Comment: @StudyStudy Water doesn't fall because of adhesion, does it?

Comment: The water molecules in the droplet are attracted to whatever they're hanging off of by adhesion, the water molecules are also attracted to each other by hydrogen bonds. The combination of these forces holds the droplet together and prevents it from falling off.

Comment: @trula If the weight of the water is increased, the water will move downward, and the pressure on the top of the water is lower than the atmospheric pressure. Right?

Comment: @enbinzheng Do note that you would not see water droplets hanging onto [water repellent materials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durable_water_repellent). This proves that the main cause behind them sticking to the surface is adhesion.

Comment: @FakeMod Is water repellent material also water repellent in vacuum?